# Designing websites on mac retina display causes size issues

Tags: responsive-design, retina-display

Anyone else have this issue? I design a responsive website layout on my mac that uses retina display and it looks fantastic. I will admit my display setting utilizes one of the more smaller size retina options. When I go to show off the design to the client, who might have a pc laptop or an older non-retina macbook everything looks gigantic for them.

Is there a trick to make the experiences a littler more consistent across the board that I am missing?

Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately, I am currently encountering the same predicament. Did you, by any chance, come up with a solution? Did you use 2 separate media queries to compose your CSS for retina & non-retina display? Any reply will be greatly appreciated thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

A couple of ideas to get you started.

If the issue you are having is with inline images then [retina.js](http://imulus.github.io/retinajs/) is an easy solution. You save regular and high resolution versions of images to your site and this JS will serve the high resolution versions to visitors with retina displays.

If you are wanting to manage images via CSS (like backgrounds) this media query will do the trick:

```
@media (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2), (min-resolution: 192dpi) { 
    /* CSS for retina displays here */
}
```

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks David, your solutions are great but I am also trying to deal with the fact that there are some perceived size differences in the heights of divs in the layout. Meaning, I could have a hero image that is 500px tall and looks great on my screen. When I sit next to a client who has a non retina, everything looks huge. That hero image might go below the fold hiding all content. I am wonder if I need to change my screen resolution to mimic what they see so I am not just designing for my screen?  Maybe I am thinking about it the wrong way?

Comment: Is the hero image a background defined by your CSS?